# is it possible to make github action auto retry with some specify error

Tags: github-actions

Recently I always facing this problem in GitHub Actions, this is the log output:

```
Run docker/build-push-action@v1
/usr/bin/docker run --name dockergithubactionsv1_b75973 --label 7b361e --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e INPUT_REGISTRY -e INPUT_USERNAME -e INPUT_PASSWORD -e INPUT_TAGS -e INPUT_REPOSITORY -e INPUT_PATH -e INPUT_TAG_WITH_REF -e INPUT_TAG_WITH_SHA -e INPUT_DOCKERFILE -e INPUT_TARGET -e INPUT_ALWAYS_PULL -e INPUT_BUILD_ARGS -e INPUT_CACHE_FROMS -e INPUT_LABELS -e INPUT_ADD_GIT_LABELS -e INPUT_PUSH -e HOME -e GITHUB_JOB -e GITHUB_REF -e GITHUB_SHA -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER -e GITHUB_RUN_ID -e GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER -e GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS -e GITHUB_ACTOR -e GITHUB_WORKFLOW -e GITHUB_HEAD_REF -e GITHUB_BASE_REF -e GITHUB_EVENT_NAME -e GITHUB_SERVER_URL -e GITHUB_API_URL -e GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL -e GITHUB_WORKSPACE -e GITHUB_ACTION -e GITHUB_EVENT_PATH -e GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_ACTION_REF -e GITHUB_PATH -e GITHUB_ENV -e RUNNER_OS -e RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE -e RUNNER_TEMP -e RUNNER_WORKSPACE -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN -e ACTIONS_CACHE_URL -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" -v "/home/runner/work/reddwarf-music/reddwarf-music":"/github/workspace" docker/github-actions:v1  "build-push"
Logging in to registry ***
WARNING! Using -*** the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: Get "https://***/v2/": Get "https://dockerauth.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/auth?account=***&client_id=docker&offline_token=true&service=registry.aliyuncs.com%3Acn-hangzhou%3A26842": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
Error: exit status 1
Usage:
  github-actions build-push [flags]

Flags:
  -h, --help   help for build-push

exit status 1
```

this error was sometimes break my GitHub Action CI workflow, sometimes it works fine. I have to login into github to check the CI success every time pushed code, is it possible to auto retry when encount this failing in CI workflow? I think it is impossible to avoid this network issue.BTW, this is my publish docker image flow code:

```
- name: Build image push to aliyun
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v1
  with:
    registry: ${{ secrets.ALI_DOCKER_HUB_REGISTRY }}
    username: ${{ secrets.ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_NAME }}
    password: ${{ secrets.ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_PASSWORD }}
    tags: ${{ github.sha }}
    repository: reddwarf-pro/dolphin-music
    path: '.'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `if: failure()` to catch the error case.

Next use [dispatch-action](https://github.com/mvasigh/dispatch-action) to trigger a [repository_dispatch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#repository_dispatch) event on the same repo. E.g.

```
on:
  repository_dispatch:
    types: [retry_job]

... etc ...

steps:
  - name: Build image push to aliyun
    uses: docker/build-push-action@v1
    with:
      registry: ${{ secrets.ALI_DOCKER_HUB_REGISTRY }}
      username: ${{ secrets.ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_NAME }}
      password: ${{ secrets.ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_PASSWORD }}
      tags: ${{ github.sha }}
      repository: reddwarf-pro/dolphin-music
      path: '.'

  - name: Retry on failure of build
    if: failure()
    uses: mvasigh/dispatch-action@main
    with:
      # You should create a personal access token and store it in your repository
      token: ${{ secrets.PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
      repo: **this-repo**
      owner: mvasigh
      event_type: retry_job
```

*I am not 100% sure this will work as I have only used the dispatch-action to trigger other workflows not the same one but I can't think why it wont.*

Answer (score 1):

Look at [wretry.action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/retry-action). Maybe, it will solve your problem.

The action can retry single Github action or shell commands. But have some restrictions.